# change checkboxlist to radiobuttonlist in visual studio

Tags: c#, asp.net

im sure this will be simple for someone, I have a asp:CheckBoxList created in visual studio 2010 I have now had to change it to a asp:RadioButtonList. However I now have the error message

runtime error: The base class includes the field 'q3', but its type (System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the type declaration in codeBehind also of your CheckBoxList.

Comment: Ive looked in the designer.cs and it has changed to a RadioButtonList in there but it still has an error. when I upload it to the server I get this error (System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBoxList) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButtonList)

Comment: Andrew don't forget end tag  </asp:RadioButtonList>

Comment: Execute Find in solution  : CTRL + MAY + F, in order to verify that you have replaced all occurences

Comment: wow a bit strange but its working now thanks everyone, it seems that even though your in the aspx part of it it needs re compiling to work